# Hpw to set -rw-rw-r-- this permission to a file on a linux server

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, operating-system

I have a file on a server which has a permission like

```
-rw-rw-r--
```

Now , I want to set this permission by using chmod or some other way

How to set this permission. I tried using

```
chmod 700 filename
```

can any one help me with this ?

Comment: `700` -> `-rwx------`, I'd suggest reading e.g. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions.

Answer (score 0):

When amending file permissions on a given file/directory, you have to set permissions for user (u), group (g) and other (o)

This can be done by specifying the permissions in octal format where:

```
1 is execute
2 is write
4 is read
```

So in your scenario, you would need to add the numbers together to get the permissions required for each of u, g and o so:

```
chmod 664 filename
```

As an alternative, you can get the permissions in the following format:

```
chmod u+rw,g+rw,o+r filename
```

So you can add permissions with + and you can also remove permissions with - e.g.

```
chmod o-r filename
```

This would remove read permission from "others"

Answer (score -1):

You should try with `chmod 664 <filename>`, this will make the permission `-rw-rw-r--`